# Check for multiple items in array using .include? -- Ruby Beginner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a better way to write this:

```
if myarray.include? 'val1' ||
   myarray.include? 'val2' ||
   myarray.include? 'val3' ||
   myarray.include? 'val4'
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Using set intersections ([Array#:&](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-26)):

```
(myarray & ["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"]).present?
```

You can also loop (`any?` will stop at the first occurrence):

```
myarray.any? { |x| ["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"].include?(x) }
```

That's ok for small arrays, in the general case you better have O(1) predicates:

```
values = ["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"].to_set
myarray.any? { |x| values.include?(x) }
```

With Ruby >= 2.1, use [Set#intersect](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-intersect-3F):

```
myarray.to_set.intersect?(values.to_set)
```

Comment: is there something simpler to read like this `if myarray.include? ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']` If not, then I guess your answer seems best.

Comment: @Hopstream, added another implementation with any?

Comment: why use the negative form ? why not just use `(self & other).any?` instead of `!(self & other).empty?`

Comment: @m_x: good point, usually _any?_ is used with a block, but it makes perfect sense without. Edited. [edit] but what if nil/false are values in the arrays? any will fail...

Comment: interesting. looking at the sources of `any?` and `empty?`, from a performance point of view, you're indeed right to use the negative form (`empty?` just checks the length of the C array, while `any?` involves a more complex process because of the _absent_ block). I learned something today.

Comment: @m_x. mee too :-) I'll put !empty again.

Comment: ooooh, right, did not think about `false`. Two lessons in two minutes !

Comment: I guess I got excited to the use the cleaner .any? form too soon :) -- back to using the .empty

Comment: Just curious... would it be possible to use a switch case here to accomplish this also?

Comment: the !empty is easily solved, adding a present? or non_empty? method to arrays. I do in my projects, I don't like negate expressions either. Why do you want a switch case here? I don't see how it fits...

Comment: hey, let's monkey-patch `Array` : `def any_value? ; !self.empty? ; end`. much cleaner.

Comment: be careful, `present?` is already added to `Array` in rails ! Third lesson today...

Comment: Why not just use `.nil?` after grabbing the intersection? I think that's fairly readable.

Answer (score 5):

Create your own reusable method:

```
class String
  def include_any?(array)
    array.any? {|i| self.include? i}
  end
end
```

#### Usage

```
"a string with many words".include_any?(["a", "string"])
```

Comment: thx a lot, it's the good answer