# A good way to check for inclusion of several items in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an options hash and a method to update it - but the options hash could change and if it does I want my tests to fail.  What's a good way to write this?

```
raise RuntimeError, msg unless options.keys.include?(
  :external_uid,
  :display_name,
  :country_code
)
```

If `options.keys` doesn't include exactly those three items, an error should be raised.

*solution that i **almost** used (thanks [bjhaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020958/bjhaid))*:

```
def ensure_correct_options!(options)
  msg = "Only 'external_uid', 'display_name' and 'country_code' can be "
  msg += "updated. Given attributes: #{options.keys.inspect}"

  raise RuntimeError, msg unless options.keys == [
    :external_uid,
    :display_name,
    :country_code
  ]
end
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026300/check-for-multiple-items-in-array-using-include-ruby-beginner) answer could help.

Comment: @Magnuss, cheers, i saw that but i wanted exact matches only...i ended up going with a much simpler/face-slap-inducing solution.  cheers

Comment: @dax, your solution would fail, if the elements in the array are ordered in a different manner have a look at [Hash#fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) has a behavior close to what you want, but on single keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options probably have a value, so I would write:

```
unless options[:external_uid] && options[:display_name] && options[:country_code]
  raise ArgumentError, ":external_uid, :display_name and :country_code required"
end
```

(I've replaced `RuntimeError` with `ArgumentError` because this seems to be about arguments)

Comment: `options.key?(...) &&...` may be preferable, as we don't know if `nil` values are permitted in the hash.

Answer (score 1):

If there were more than three values to test for inclusion as keys in the hash, you might do it t like this:

```
unless ([:external_uid, :display_name,...] - options.keys).empty? \
  raise ArgumentError, ":external_uid, :display_Nam,... are required"
```