# Ruby refactor include? that takes in multiple strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following logic, if true I'm rendering a partial.

```
@taxon.tag.present? && @taxon.tag.include?('shirts') || @taxon.tag.present? && @taxon.tag.include?('dibs')
```

I'm trying have the following behaviour: `if taxon.tag is present and includes shirts or dibs`

render my partial.

I don't like that I'm repeating code so much.

I tried `@taxon.tag.present? && %w(shirts dibs)include?(@taxon.canonical_tag)` didn't work because tag for shirts is: "shirts/url/url" it would work if it was "shirts"

what would  be a quick way to refactor this?

Comment: I believe `present?` is from Rails. If so, you should add a Rails tag or stick with pure Ruby methods.

Comment: I think it's part of active support, it's defined as def present?   !blank? end so using blank? would be the same  if you're on plain ruby

Comment: Ruby doesn't have `blank?` either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be

```
( (@taxon.tag || []) & ["shirts", "dibs"] ).present?
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026300/check-for-multiple-items-in-array-using-include-ruby-beginner) might be helpful.

Let me try to explain the solution:

```
# @taxon.tag looks like an enumerable, but it could also be nil as you check it with
# .present? So to be safe, we do the following
(@taxon.tag || [])
# will guarentee to return an enumerable

# The & does an intersection of two arrays
# [1,2,3] & [3,4,5] will return 3
(@taxon.tag || []) & ["shirts, "dibs"]
# will return the common value, so if shirts and dibs are empty, will return empty

( (@taxon.tag || []) & ["shirts, "dibs"] ).present?
# should do what you set out to do
```

Comment: Defining a constant for the tags would help here.

Comment: amazing, ended up going with `@taxon.tag.present? && ['shirts', 'dibs'].present?`

Comment: @neo That isn't going to do what you want, it's just checking if `@taxon.tag` is present, since the latter clause is always true. `&` is not the same as `&&`.

Comment: Make sure that it isn't just always returning true if @taxon.tag is non-nil, because that's what the code in your comment will do.